# Проблема с байдингом

Tags: c#, wpf

Идея такова: вводим текст в `TextBox`, и сразу обрабатываем событие ввода с клавиатуры, но получается что ввод с клавиатуры обрабатывается раньше чем байдинг текста. Как это исправить?

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Text="{Binding Path=Source, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=Input}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: `KeyDown` -> `PreviewKeyDown` не пробовали?

Comment: @Monk, пробовал, эффект тот же.

Comment: Почему Вы не хотите в Source set{ }  обрабатывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, KeyDown происходит раньше, чем собственно изменение текста, более того, это изменение - есть следствие нажатия клавиши. Изменение даже можно блокировать (частично, с глюками, но все же), если в стандартной реализации обработчика _KeyDown написать e.Handled=true;
Возможны 2 варианта: 
1. использовать другое событие, например KeyUp;
2. Итоговую Команду вызывать не по событию, а из блока set поля 'Source', к которому привязан TextBox (хотя архитектурно это возможно коряво)